# Finding numbers in an array above the average number

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to figure out why my code won't allow me to correctly print any values in the array that are above the average value. I looked at a stackoverflow example of another user with a similar issue but it still didn't make sense. I don't even understand the current output for the values above the average.

How do I print the values in the array that are above the calculated average of all the array values?

I'd appreciate the help.

My code:

```
public class Inequality 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // list of incomes in thousands
         int[] income = {2,10, 532, 4, 53, 28, 291, 38, 6, 17, 73, 21};
         int sum = 0;
         int average;
         int aboveAverage = 0;

         for (int i = 0;i< income.length;i++)
         {
             sum = sum + income[i];
         }
         average = sum/income.length;
         System.out.println("Average of income array: " + average);

         for (int i = 0; i < income.length; i++)
         {
             if (income[i]>average)
             {
                 aboveAverage++;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("There are " + aboveAverage + " numbers above the average.");
         System.out.println("Range of numbers above the average: " + income);
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Average of income array: 89
There are 2 numbers above the average.
Range of numbers above the average: [I@15db9742
```

Comment: You are printing the whole array object. What makes you think `income` would be contain the numbers above the average?

Comment: You print the above-average values in a similar way to how you're counting them: With a loop, an `if` statement, and a `print` statement. Or just add a `print` statement to the loop you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Name of arrays with be the base address so in last line

```
System.out.println("Range of numbers above the average: " + income);
```

printing name will just print some address of array not any value. So if you need to fetch value you have to print like this

```
income[<index>] eg. income[1] , income[2]
```

Now About you wish of printing all values which are greater than average.
just print it where you are comparing with average.
so here is the code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < income.length; i++)
     {
         if (income[i]>average)
         {
             aboveAverage++;
             System.out.println("Number above the average: " + income[i]);

         }
     }
```

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: A simple explanation would improve this answer.

Comment: Code is self explanatory, I thought you already got how many numbers are there above average so another thing is like print them. All numbers can be printed inside loops with check icome[i]>average.

Comment: If you want to do anything else. Please update your questions.

Comment: Are you somehow under the *mistaken* impression that *I* asked the question? I'm the person who up-voted your answer as being useful, but I think the answer can be *more* useful for newbies with a little explanation, including a disclaimer that your output will be different that the expected output in the question, e.g. you re-print the leading text for every number, instead of a comma-separated list on a single line.

Answer (score -1):

You are printing the data value (I think that is what it's called) you need to do...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

or for you

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(income));
```

This should work for you!

Comment: That just prints the whole array, I am looking for it to print the values in the array that are above the average calculated value.

Comment: @Aramza Then you need to iterate and only print the ones above the average. Or filter them out into a new array. All you do know is total the ones above the average--why not print them at the same time?